# how make docker container listening to instant changes?

Tags: reactjs, docker

I am currently working on React(UI) and I need to see the changes on the dom every time I change the code on my code editor, I am sure there is there a way to keep the container listening to the changes and update the image instantly?

- not sure what is exactly the solution but maybe volume command or something like that.
  **here is my docker file**

````
FROM node:12.6.0-alpine 
RUN apk update && apk add git 
# set working directory 
RUN mkdir /app 
COPY . /app 
WORKDIR /app 
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH 
RUN yarn 
# start app 
CMD ["npm", "start"]```
````

Comment: Docker is designed as an isolation environment: one of the major points of running something in a container is that it will be unaffected by changes in the host system.  Would it meet your needs for day-to-day development to run Node directly on the host, without involving Docker at all?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/). Volumes are file storage regions owned and operated by the container whereas a bind mount provides file access via a directory reference. `npm start` will start the development server within the docker container but watch for changes to the application files which will be referenced by the bind mount and mutable through an editor running on the host machine